# Edit Favorite Tags > Set Focus to TextBox

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, tag-watching

When editing "Favorite Tags" on S.O. (and other S.E. sites), would it be possible to set focus to the `interestingTab` input TextBox after clicking the *edit* link?

Currently, the *edit* link must be clicked, followed by a 2nd click into the TextBox to begin typing tags; whereas, if the focus was immediately set to the TextBox after clicking the *edit* link, no further mouse clicks would be required.